# When two or three user request the same time then I have duplicate ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I get the last ID and increment it and store it as second ID of my invoice when two or three user request at the same time it store duplicated ID in DB. HERE IS THE CODE

```
$id_num = DB::table('slips')->latest('id')->first();
$now = \jDate::forge('now')->format('date');
$old = $id_num->date;
$slep_id = 0;

 if($now>$old){
    $slep_id = 1;
}
else{
    $slep_id = $id_num->id_num+1;
}
$formatted_slep = sprintf("%04d",$slep_id);
```

Now when I store it in the DB it some times it duplicate

```
$slip = new Slip;
$slip->id = $formatted_slep;
$slip->save();
```

Comment: simple dear just use rand function and assigne in sesseion and save it

Comment: mysql can return the auto-increment id that was assigned in an insert-query. You should not calculate it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction :

```
DB::transaction(function () {
   $slip = new Slip;
   $slip->id = $formatted_slep;
   $slip->save();
});
```